# Python "global name 'x' is not defined"

Tags: python

```
from dionaea.core import ihandler, incident, g_dionaea
from dionaea.util import md5file, sha512file
from dionaea import pyev

import logging
import json
import uuid

logger = logging.getLogger('submit_http')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

class submmithttp_report:
    def __init__(self, sha512h, md5, filepath):
        self.sha512h, self.md5h, self.filepath = sha512h, filepath
        self.saddr, self.sport, self.daddr, self.dport = ('', )*4
        self.download_url = ''


class handler(ihandler):
    def __init__(self, path):
        logger.debug("%s ready!" % (self.__class__.__name__))
        ihandler.__init__(self, path)
        mwsconfig = g_dionaea.config()['modules']['python']['submit_http']
        self.backendurl = mwsconfig['url']
        self.email = 'email' in mwsconfig and mwsconfig['email'] or 'dionaea@carnivore.it'
        self.user = 'user' in mwsconfig and mwsconfig['user'] or ''
        self.password = 'pass' in mwsconfig and mwsconfig['pass'] or ''
        self.cookies = {}

        # heartbeats
        dinfo = g_dionaea.version()
        self.software = 'dionaea {0} {1}/{2} - {3} {4}'.format(
            dinfo['dionaea']['version'],
            dinfo['compiler']['os'],
            dinfo['compiler']['arch'],
            dinfo['compiler']['date'],
            dinfo['compiler']['time'],
        )
        self.loop = pyev.default_loop()

    def handle_incident(self, icd):
        pass

    def handle_incident_dionaea_download_complete_unique(self, icd):
        cookie = str(uuid.uuid4())

        i = incident("dionaea.upload.request")
        i._url = self.backendurl

        i.sha512 = sha512file(icd.file)
        i.md5 = md5file(icd.file)
        i.email = self.email
        i.user = self.user
        i.password = self.password

        mr = submithttp_report(i.sha512, i.md5, icd.file)

        if hasattr(icd, 'con'):
            i.source_host = icd.con.remote.host
            i.source_port = str(icd.con.remote.port)
            i.target_host = icd.con.local.host
            i.target_port = str(icd.con.local.port)
            mr.saddr, mr.sport, mr.daddr, mr.dport = i.saddr, i.sport, i.daddr, i.dport
        if hasattr(icd, 'url'):
            i.download_url = icd.url
            mr.download_url = icd.url

        i._callback = "dionaea.modules.python.submithttp.result"
        i._userdata = cookie

        self.cookies[cookie] = mr
        i.report()

    # handle agains in the same way
    handle_incident_dionaea_download_complete_again = handle_incident_dionaea_download_complete_unique

    def handle_incident_dionaea_modules_python_submithttp_result(self, icd):
        fh = open(icd.path, mode="rb")
        c = fh.read()
        logger.info("submithttp result: {0}".format(c))

        cookie = icd._userdata
        mr = self.cookies[cookie]

        # does backend want us to upload?
        if b'UNKNOWN' in c or b'S_FILEREQUEST' in c:
            i = incident("dionaea.upload.request")
            i._url = self.backendurl

            i.sha512 = mr.sha512h
            i.md5 = mr.md5h
            i.email = self.email
            i.user = self.user
            i.password = self.password

            i.set('file://data', mr.filepath)

            i.source_host = mr.saddr
            i.source_port = mr.sport
            i.target_host = mr.daddr
            i.target_port = mr.dport
            i.download_url = mr.download_url

            i._callback = "dionaea.modules.python.submithttp.uploadresult"
            i._userdata = cookie

            i.report()

    def handle_incident_dionaea_modules_python_submithttp_uploadresult(self, icd):
        fh = open(icd.path, mode="rb")
        c = fh.read()
        logger.info("submithttp uploadresult: {0}".format(c))

        del self.cookies[icd._userdata]
```

When the honeypot call this module the following error appears:

```
NameError at NameError("global name 'submithttp_report' is not defined",)
[11022011 00:27:30] python module.c:984: /opt/dionaea/lib/dionaea/python/dionaea/submit_http.py:57 in handle_incident_dionaea_download_complete_unique
[11022011 00:27:30] python module.c:985:     mr = submithttp_report(i.sha512, i.md5, icd.file)
[11022011 00:27:30] python module.c:984: binding.pyx:975 in dionaea.core.c_python_ihandler_cb (binding.c:8605)
```

Thanck you guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class name is `submmithttp_report` but you are calling `submithttp_report`

Comment: (To be even more explicit: there are 2 `m` characters in the class definition name.)

Comment: I am at two hours looking at the code and have not noticed, as I saw today thousands of lines of code is normal that not noticed.

I apologize and thank you!

Comment: Now i have this stupid error, but this seems to me that any bug in python or am I wrong? Error: ValueError at ValueError('need more than 2 values to unpack',)
[11022011 00:44:53] python module.c:984: /opt/dionaea/lib/dionaea/python/dionaea/submit_http.py:15 in __init__
[11022011 00:44:53] python module.c:985:      self.sha512h, self.md5h, self.filepath = sha512h, filepath